# files's binary data stored as variable inside python file

Tags: python, encoding, exe, binary-data

Lets say a have  program.exe , i will create a python script that will

- read program.exe in binary mode and save it in variable data
- open mypytonprog.py in binary append mode
- append data to mypythonprog.py (?)

before this, mypythonprog.py would be prepared as:

```
program_data='''
```

after it, mypythonprog.py would continue as:

```
'''
programs continues....
```

(i want somehow to put that program code into a program_data variable)

This,  does **not** work,of course, but can it be done in some way ?
What i want basicly is:  mypythonfile.py to be able to create an exe file with binary data stored inside it.

I suppouse i have to encode that data to a shellcode to by able to put it inside mypythonfile.py,
  right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import base64

exe = 'c:/users/me/program.exe'
script = 'c:/users/me/newpython.py'
chunksize = 6144
linelength = 80

with open(exe,'rb') as inf, open(script,'w') as outf:
    outf.write('program_data = """')

    while True:
        progdata = inf.read(chunksize)
        if len(progdata):
            progdata = progdata.encode("base64")
            outf.writelines(progdata[i:i+linelength] for i in range(0, len(progdata), linelength))
        else:
            break

    outf.write('""".decode("base64")')
```

**Edit:**

The idea is to process the input file in convenient chunks rather than reading a potentially-huge file into memory.

After base64-encoding the chunk, I then split it into 80-char lines (this is basically just to keep it manageable in the text editor) and write it to output.

I wrap the data in program_data = """ .. """.decode("base64") such that when Python loads the file, the data will be automatically decrypted - program_data will contain the binary data you desire.

8096 was a brain fart - I meant to use 8192 bytes (8KB). Then I realized there was a second problem; encoding a chunk other than a multiple of 3 chars long results in '='-padded output, which prematurely truncates decoding. I have changed the chunk size to 6KB = 512 bytes (default NTFS block size) * 3 chars * 4 (arbitrary multiple); this seems to work as expected.

Hope that helps!

Comment: well, this is surely better than @Ignacio answer ( it doesnt give me any arrors....about non-ASCII charracters...) but when i write that program_data in (binary?) mode to file ( and close is) windows gives me an arror that it isnt a valid Win32 aplication....

Comment: could you descire a bit what is it doing ? why chunksize = 8096 ? i see what it is doing, but why ? what is your stategy ? :-) thx

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> 'some binary data'.encode('base64')
'c29tZSBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YQ==\n'
>>> 'c29tZSBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YQ==\n'.decode('base64')
'some binary data'
```